# How to select from list filtering through IN

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, casting

Q:

I have a list of objects like this:

`List<object> entities = GetallEntities();`

The first object in the previous list is : `List<Books>`.

Now i wanna to get all the books which `id`

exist in the following list:

`List<string> BookIds = new List<string>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `Books` class has an `Id` property and one instance represents one book:

```
// Get the first element of your entity-list which is of type `List<Books>`
List<Books> bookList = entities.OfType<List<Books>>().First();
List<string> BookIds = new List<string>();
// fill your id list here ...

// filter your books by the list of ids
IEnumerable<Books> filteredBooks = 
               bookList.Where(b => BookIds.Any(id => id == b.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Book
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
List<object> entities = new List<object> { new Book { id = "1" }, new Book { id = "2" } };
List<string> bookIds = new List<string> { "2" };

IEnumerable<object> books = entities.Where(e => e is Book && bookIds.Contains(((Book)e).id));
```